# How can I send a message to a specific thread?

Tags: rust

I need to create some threads where some of them are going to run until their runner variable value has been changed. This is my minimal code.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut log_runner = Arc::new(Mutex::new(true));
    println!("{}", *log_runner.lock().unwrap());
    let mut threads = Vec::new();

    {
        let mut log_runner_ref = Arc::clone(&log_runner);
        // log runner thread
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            while *log_runner_ref.lock().unwrap() == true {
                // DO SOME THINGS CONTINUOUSLY
                println!("I'm a separate thread!");
            }
        });
        threads.push(handle);
    }

    // let the main thread to sleep for x time
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
    // stop the log_runner thread
    *log_runner.lock().unwrap() = false;
    // join all threads
    for handle in threads {
        handle.join().unwrap();
        println!("Thread joined!");
    }
    println!("{}", *log_runner.lock().unwrap());
}
```

It looks like I'm able to set the `log_runner_ref` in the log runner thread after 1 second to `false`. Is there a way to mark the treads with some name / ID or something similar and send a message to a specific thread using its specific marker (name / ID)?

If I understand it correctly, then the `let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();` can be used for sending messages to all the threads simultaneously rather than to a specific one. I could send some identifier with the messages and each thread will be looking for its own identifier for the decision if to act on received message or not, but I would like to avoid the broadcasting effect.

Comment: `mpsc` is not meant for broadcasting, it is multiple producer single consumer(specific one), so it can do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPSC stands for Multiple Producers, Single Consumer. As such, no, you cannot use that *by itself* to send a message to all threads, since for that you'd have to be able to duplicate the consumer. There **are** tools for this, but the choice of them requires a bit more info than just "MPMC" or "SPMC".

Honestly, if you can rely on channels for messaging (there are cases where it'd be a bad idea), you can create a channel per thread, assign the ID outside of the thread, and keep a `HashMap` instead of a `Vec` with the IDs associated to the threads. `Receiver<T>` can be moved into the thread (it implements `Send` if `T` implements `Send`), so you can quite literally `move` it in.

You then keep the `Sender` outside and send stuff to it :-)